# MS Azure: Could not submit the request to create database 'Name'

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I had pay-as-you-go subscription. After getting Bizspark subscription, I took backup of database and website. I disabled pay-as-you-go subscription.

When I tried to create MS SQL Server database, it is giving me **"Could not submit the request to create database 'EutheniaDB'. Failed to create the database server."** error.

When I am trying to create new Website with SQL Server database it is giving me same error. But when I create a new website without SQL Server it is creating successfully.

Does anyone have face similar problem? Am I forgetting something  to configure?

Please help!

Comment: Yep, got the same issue. No idea about the solution though...

Answer (score 0):

We sometimes see this if the time between the deletion and the attempt to restore is short. We also find that trying again after a few minutes works great.